# Cannot call toll free numbers or 3-digit numbers using voip.ms with softphone apps

Tags: voip, sip

With my LAN phone plugged into a Grandstream HT701 ATA, I am able to call toll-free numbers and three digit numbers like 311 and 211 with my voip.ms account. When I call 3-digit numbers with my Android phone using cSipSimple or Zoiper, I get a voice message that says "The number you have dialed has not been recognized". When I call toll free numbers with those apps I get a voice message that says "41611" with cSipSimple and "41613" with Zoiper, followed by "We're sorry because of technical difficulties we are unable to route your call". I am able to dial regular 10 digit phone numbers without any problems.

Is there a way to fix this or is this just a limitation of softphone apps? I also don't get the above errors with Android's native SIP client but I would like to use cSipSimple for it's features e.g. call recording.

Comment: Not clear is this question is related to Android. One place to check is that you aren't reusing account names per: http://wiki.voip.ms/article/FAQ#Can_I_register_2_or_more_different_devices_with_the_same_account_username.3F

Comment: @Morrison No, my Android phone and LAN phone are using different subaccounts.  https://wiki.voip.ms/article/Sub_Accounts

Comment: three digit numbers????